# how can i menction specific offset to be deducted while saving times or datetime in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone, spreadsheet

I am having a `datetime` column to store `employee` `check-in ,out times`. my logic in the controller action to capture check-in is,

```
def check_in
 @employee = current_user.employee
 punch_record = @employee.in_outs.where("date = ?", Date.today).first
 punch_record.check_in = DateTime.now 
 punch_record.save
end
```

when a person clicks `check-in` then the above logic gets executed.And in database it saves the `check-in` by deducting the `indian offset` ,that is `(05:30)`. and in `view page`, i am using the `in_time_zone` method to show the `check_in` time, back in `indian timezone`,so that its adding the `offset(05:30)`. and the time is showing properly. this is working fine.

```
record.check_in.in_time_zone(record.time_zone).strftime(" %I:%M %P")
```

here the record time_zone = `Mumbai`

now i am facing the `time_zone` issue in `import` attendance, where a person fills the `employee` `check-in`,`out times` in `spreadsheet` and uploads it. the `format` that is used in `excel` sheet is `09:30 am`.

so here i am using the following logic to convert it into `datetime`.

```
  irb(main):004:0> "09:30 am".to_datetime
  => Mon, 07 Nov 2016 09:30:00 +0000
```

here in this case the offset(05:30) is not getting deducted. how to make the offset deducted in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't comparing like with like.

In the first case you are doing:

```
record.check_in.in_time_zone(record.time_zone)
```

Which is taking the recorded datetime object (9:30 am) and converting it to the relevant time zone.

In the second case:

```
"09:30 am".to_datetime
```

Which is just setting date time to 9:30 am - you are doing nothing to convert it.

Replicate your logic in rails console by doing:

```
"09:30 am".to_datetime.in_time_zone('Kolkata')
```

and you will find you get the right result.

If "9:30 am" is input that isn't UTC but represents the time in India itself, then to convert it to UTC simply do:

```
"9:30".in_time_zone('Kolkata').utc
 => 2016-11-07 04:00:00 UTC
```

Comment: no its not working. instead of deducting the offset its adding the offset. i checked in rails console. this is the output => Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.5)
irb(main):001:0> "09:30 am".to_datetime.in_time_zone('Kolkata')
=> Mon, 07 Nov 2016 15:00:00 IST +05:30
irb(main):002:0>

Comment: isn't that correct? India isn't 5 and a half hours behind - it's +5:30 gmt. So 9:30 am gmt should be 3 pm in india.

Comment: By default datetime is stored in database as UTC (which is currently GMT +0) ... ideally you should leave that as UTC, which I believe you are doing, and just do conversion when reading from it (which again I believe you are doing).

Comment: ok i think i understand what you are trying to do now - 9:30 am is the time IN india that is inputted by the user and you want to convert that to UTC - I will update my solution appropriately